# [][] gives a SyntaxError in Python

Tags: python

I wrote this code but it gives an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the first line:

```
a =[][]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i][j] = i+j
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can google the syntax or read about it in a book

Answer (score 6):

`[][]` is not valid syntax. There are no true multi-dimensional arrays in Python, only lists of lists. Also, lists do not automatically expand to any index you throw at them. You have to expand them manually by using, for instance, the `append`method.

If you want a "two-dimensional array", first create the top-level list:

```
a = []
```

Then add sub-lists to it within a loop

```
for i in range(3):
    row = []
    a.append(row)
    for j in range(3):
        row.append(i+j)
```

There are more succinct ways to initialize such a list structure, but this is a way that's closer to your code.

If you want to quickly initialize a list to a certain size, you can use the `*` operator on a list:

```
>>> [0] * 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Just be careful if you're using more complex types as items than numbers or strings; you might end up with a list where all the elements are actually references to the same object.

(Before somebody points out that there are packages that offer multi-dimensional arrays, such as `numpy`, I think it would be a good idea for the OP to learn more common types first.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate a 5 x 5 dimensional array

```
>>> array = [ [i+j for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
>>> array
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As you know, `[]` is the empty list. Further `some_list[i]` accesses `some_list` at index `i`. So when python sees `[][]` it first sees the empty list, followed by a opening bracket. It then assumes you want to access the empty list and expects an index or a slice. When it then encounters the closing bracket instead, this is unexpected and causes your syntax error.

To create a list containing lists, you can do `[[], [], []]` (which is a list containing three empty lists). However since you're using a loop, you rather want to populate the array in the loop, which would look like this:

```
a =[]
for i in range(3):
    a.append( [] )
    for j in range(3):
        a[i].append( i+j )
```

However that is still not really what you want to do is that is much too verbose. What you should do is use a list comprehension like this:

```
a = [[i+j for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: In your example `a[i] = []` will not work. Please use `a.append([])`. Also `a[i][j] = i+j` should be `a[i].append(i+j)`

Comment: @Rumple: Yeah, I've already noticed and fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Like Matti said, `[][]` is not a valid syntax, you have to manually add the list to the first list.

```
a = []

for i in range(3):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        a[i].append(i+j)
```